# Best approach to transfer many data from a Mongo collection to another with a criteria

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with around 1400 millions of documents. I want to split this collection into multiple collections.
The final result will be around 10 collections with 140 millions each.

I have tested some approachs, but every one is too slow. Which one would be the best? There are another alternatives?

1º Aggregation Framework

```
db.getCollection("Measurement.AERNET").aggregate([
    {$match: {"sensor": {"$in": 
['aernet06_74.199:c','aernet06_74.192:c','aernet06_74.206:c','aernet06_74.100:h','aernet06_74.130:c']
    }}},
    {$out: 'Measurement.aernet06'}
]);
```

2º Mongoexport and then import json to new table

```
 mongoexport --username=xxxxx--authenticationDatabase=prod -port=27017 --password=xxxxx -d=prod -c=Measurement.AERNET -q='{"sensor": {"$in": 
['aernet06_74.199:c','aernet06_74.192:c','aernet06_74.206:c','aernet06_74.100:h','aernet06_74.130:c']}}' --out=aernet06.json
```

NOTE: I have simplified the $in clause because there are around 200 elements on in. I have also tested a regular expression with a similar result.
`{$match: {"sensor": /aernet06\.*/}}`

Comment: Do you use sharding? Would be much easier.

Comment: No, nowadays the server is a replica set with only one node.

Comment: For 1.4 billion documents you should consider sharing.